# Looking for an accurate algorithm to find the area of a oscillatory function

Tags: algorithms, integration

As the title suggests, I'm looking for a very accurate algorithm to find the area under an oscillatory  function.

For instance, I would like to integrate the following graph[image]

I'm currently using simpson's method to integrate this, but I was wondering if there are more accurate methods.

Comment: Your test function looks smooth (infinitely often differentiable), to me. Did you mean to write oscillatory instead?

Comment: In what form is the function given?  Do you have an analytic or partially analytic form, or is black box or defined by interpolation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can look up various quadratures. One method that should fair better is Gauss Quadrature.

I would also recommend looking into any adaptive quadrature schemes. There are many of them out there, so searching up algorithms for adaptive integration would help you.

[This wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_quadrature) should give you some insight into adaptive integration.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm going to look into it and come back to this answer